# how do I swap the elements of 2 arrays of different types of the same length?

Tags: arrays, assembly, x86

Not sure if I need a third array to temporarily store values in order to swap contents of arrayA and arrayB. I am a student learning assembly for the first time so please keep it simple.

```
.386
.model flat,stdcall ; memory system
.stack 4096 ; declare stack memory size 4kb
ExitProcess proto,dwExitCode:dword
.data

arrayA byte 01d, 04d, 02d ; 8bits
arrayB word 02d, 05d, 05d ; 16bits

.code
main proc

mov EAX, 0
    mov EBX, 0
    mov ECX, 3
    mov EDX, 0

    L1:
        movzx bx, arrayA[ebx]
        mov ax, arrayB[ebx]

        xchg arrayA[ebx], al 
        xchg arrayB[ebx], bx

        inc ebx
        loop L1


    invoke ExitProcess,0
main endp
end main
```

Comment: Once  you've loaded the array element values into CPU registers, there's no need to use `xchg`, as you can simply store the register values back to the opposite memory locations.

Comment: However, you cannot both use `ebx`  as an index and also use `bx` as a temporary to hold an array element -- that will wipe out use of `ebx` as index.  Try single stepping, and you'll see.

Comment: can I substitute bx with a different register like dx?

Comment: yes, `dx` should work where you are using `bx` now.  Alternatively, you could substitute the other: `ebx`, with `esi` or `edi`, for example.  Just as long as we don't put two different variables in the same register at the same time!

Comment: thanks for the help, just to clarify, if I replace bx with register dx, the arrays should swap contents right? my instructor wanted us to use xchg as part of an exercise. i want to make sure I'm doing this right.

Comment: Yes, that should do it.  FWIW, using `xchg` this way will work but is overkill and not helping you at all over simple moving to memory.  So, you might want to check with your instructor to see if there's a shorter code sequence you would use that would necessitate `xchg`.  Let's note that `xchg` can both read and write memory in one instruction, so in theory there's a shorter code sequence that doesn't need the initial loads (those `mov`'s).

Comment: @ErikEidt: Normally you'd avoid `xchg` with mem because you don't need or want to use a slow atomic RMW exchange.  (`xchg` with mem is unfortunately atomic like `lock add`.)  2 loads + 2 stores is the most performance-efficient way, vs. 1 movzx load, 1 xchg, 1 mov-store being slightly smaller code-size.

Comment: But if you were optimizing for code-size, you'd probably use a pointer to hold an address to save the disp32 in every instruction.  Like `mov edx, OFFSET arrayA - 1` outside the loop.  Inside the loop, maybe `movzx eax, byte ptr [edx + ecx]` / `xchg [edx + (arrayB-1) - (arrayA-2)  + ecx*2], ax` / `mov [edx + ecx], al` so we can use the ECX down-counter as a scaled index, and only two total disp32 / imm32 32-bit addresses.  (It would also be possible to avoid indexed addressing modes in the movzx and mov, incrementing a pointer and having another register holding `(arrayB-1) - (arrayA-2)`)

Comment: In any case, `movzx bx` should be a `movzx ebx`; there's no reason to use a less efficient instruction that only writes a 16-bit partial register when you could zero-extend to the full register.

Comment: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=82369 has an example of using a pointer to one array as a scaled index into another array, for a loop over 2 arrays with different sized elements.  Compact instructions inside the loop, but needs more setup.  (@ErikEidt if you're interested.)